# Placing another array in my table

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I currently use 2 arrays to place values in my table like so:

```
echo "<table>";
    foreach ($products as $key => $product){
      $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
            if (!$number){
            echo "";
            } else {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $product;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $number;
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

The $product and $number are showing just fine, but my problem is that i need a third column  with the $prices in them. Looking like this:

```
            echo "<td>";
                echo $price;
            echo "</td>";
```

I made an array for $prices looking like this:

```
$prices = array(7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 5, 5.50, 6, 0.50, 0.50);
```

But it gets more complicated.

It needs to be so that $price = $number * $prices.

Meaning that if $number = 5 and $prices = 8 it should place 40 in the $price.

I don't know if this is easy to do or not. But i'd like some help with this since im not really familiar with arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _“It needs to be so that $prices = $number * $price”_ – and what _is_ $price?

Comment: $price is what it places in my table in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<table>";
$count = 0;
    foreach ($products as $key => $product){
      $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
            if (!$number){
            $count++;
            echo "";
            } else {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $product;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $number;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            $price = $prices[$count] * $number;
            echo $price;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $count++;
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: thanks! this works exactly how i want to, however. as you can see in my script it says if(!$number) it wont show anything, however it will still show the price. So if it was 1, 2, 3 and price a, b, c but someone decides to not order 2. It will show as 1, 3 and a, b. If you know what i mean...

Comment: Okay I'm not really sure if I get you, because I don't know for sure what your array looks like, but I've edited my post so the code also raises the count if !$number. So now it will also show 1,3 and a,c. Right?

Comment: Yes!! Thanks man, this is exactly what I ment, i kinda should've figured this out myself but thanks for the effort you took to help me!